# DefaultValueAttribute for PropertyGrid throws exception

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, propertygrid

I have the following custom class that I use for PropertyGrid. As an example:

```
[DefaultPropertyAttribute("SaveOnClose")]
public class MyData
{
    private UInt32 _MaximumUploadFileSizeKB = _k_MaximumUploadFileSizeKB;

    const UInt32 _k_MaximumUploadFileSizeKB = 262144;

    [CategoryAttribute("Server Settings"),
    DefaultValueAttribute(_k_MaximumUploadFileSizeKB),
    DescriptionAttribute("The maximum allowed upload file size in KBytes.")]
    public UInt32 MaximumUploadFileSizeKB
    {
        get { return _MaximumUploadFileSizeKB; }
        set 
        {
            _MaximumUploadFileSizeKB = value > 0 ? value : 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Where the PropertyGrid is initialized as such:

```
PropertyGrid propertyGrid = new PropertyGrid();

propertyGrid.SelectedObject = new MyData();
```

That works, but when I try to set the currently selected property grid item to a default value:

```
void ResetFieldToDefault()
{
    propertyGrid.ResetSelectedProperty();   //Throws exception
}
```

It throws this exception:

> Object of type 'System.Int64' cannot be converted to type
>   'System.UInt32'.

I don't see anywhere in my code where I'd use `Int64` type. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: What's the full stack trace? It maybe somewhere else in your code

Comment: @SimonMourier: No, it's something in the way `DefaultValueAttribute` operates. If I define my parameter as `Int64` or as a custom type it works just fine. For some reason it has an issue with `UInt32`.

Comment: If you want help, please put the full stack trace, also how is the SaveOnClose property defined